# Is Azure Service Bus supposed to replace your SOA

Tags: c#, azure, soa, azureservicebus

Previously in my web applications when a CRUD operation (or any other task for that matter) was made (from the UI) I would use a simple pattern like the following utilizing WCF.

```
GetUserByIDResponse response = new UserServiceClientProxy().GetByID(new GetUserByIDRequest() { UserID = UserID });

if (response.success) {
    //response.data - Do something!
} else {
    //Show error response.message
}
```

From my research however it seems that if deploying with the intention to run from the Azure platform and using the [Cloud Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/fundamentals/compute/) model the best approach is to use this service bus concept with code like the following

```
QueueClient requestClient = CreateQueueClient("RequestQueueName"); 
QueueClient responseClient = CreateQueueClient("ResponseQueueName");

MessageSession receiver = responseClient.AcceptMessageSession(ReplyToSessionId); 
//blah blah
```

When communicating is my assumption that all my service type operations now be handled through service bus correct? Or would you only look at using this technique in some particular aspects of your application?

I guess what I am asking is, "Is service bus a general replacement for a SOA (Service-oriented architecture) designed for the Azure platform?"

Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Is service bus a general replacement for a SOA (Service-oriented
>   architecture) designed for the Azure platform?"

Definitely **NOT**!

What you do now with WCF in Web Application, you can certainly do exactly the same in Cloud Services and don't worry!

Azure Service Bus Queues, and Azure Storage Queues are (in my view) mechanisms for decoupling application blocks/modules. Say you have a module A (or a web application) which needs to send some long-running-heavy-cpu-intensive task to be completed by module B. Module B however is designed to only be ON (available) during night hours. Module A can safely send task message to a queue and forget about it. Module B will "wake up" later and check the Queue for any task messages. Will process the tasks one by one (or in parallel, it doesn't really matter now) and can report results to another queue, or other form of notification.

Going deeper in Azure Service Bus Queues, they understand and implement the `Publish-Subscribe` pattern. Meaning that you may have one publisher (that sends messages to a queue), but multiple subscribers (that read from the queue). Even more - you can apply filters for each subscriber.

A step further, ASB is more like Enterprise Service Bus, or BizTalk in the cloud (I'm not saying **it is**, I say **it is similar** to BizTalk).

In summary:

Use the WCF in Windows Azure Cloud Services as you use them in your current setup. Azure Service Bus is not a "replacement" for WCF. It has another purpose.

**UPDATE**

I would say `use queues when you want to *decouple* system components`. Decoupling means Module A (caller) **does not depend** on the availability of Module B (executor).

In the case of WCF service we have very tight coupling between Module A (caller) and Module B (WCF). If the WCF Service is not available than the caller immediately fails.

In your particular case, where you have WCF services to process UI calls it is acceptable to heavily rely on the WCF service. Especially in the case you host the WCF service in the Web Application as the UI itself.

But in the scenario I have a desktop Application (Module A) that has to send task to some remote executor (Module B) and this task needs to be send reliably and regardless of executor availability, I would use some Queue.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. So is it fair to say that the service bus queues should only be used when you have particularly long running operations?

Comment: I would not say it depends on the long running operations.  It mostly comes down to having asynchronous processing and decoupling of service and client.
Service bus messaging enables asynchronous messaging scenarios, such as temporal decoupling, publish/subscribe, load leveling, and load balancing.

Answer (score 0):

No; neither WCF nor ASB is a replacement for SOA since neither is SOA.

SOA implies services. ASB is a message broker and minimal pieces of actual service bus. WCF is a RPC framework.

Services are programs that run independently regardless of what software you use to link them together. Often they are linked together with queues, and they also need some identity, ability to route or look up other services. They often consume other services as resources.

With regards to WCF - if you are doing your SOA that way, you are basically making a mess of your architecture. If you want to use ASB, I can recommend MassTransit-AzureServiceBus, which takes care of a lot of the annoying routing logic, retry logic, in-proc queueing, async calling and message handling logic that the not-service-bus Azure Service Bus doesn't implement.

Comment: While I appreciate the answer, WCF does provide XML and JSON endpoints if you configure them and I would still argue is at the heart of a SOA in .Net and while I also accept that Service Bus doesn't fit the exact definition of a SOA it fits one that is used within your application. I'd also be curious to know why you see issues with implementing our service layer as described above, this is quite a standard way of doing it.

Comment: My approach is basically taken straight out of Professional ASP.NET Design Patterns by Scott Millett (not that it can't be wrong)

Comment: I'd argue about WCF being just RPC and not the Microsoft's tool for SOA. Will also argue that ASB (and specifically the .NET client) doesn't implement async calling, retry logic, message handling logic and all the gooides you are talking about. That ASB doesn't do `in-proc queueing` I will agree, but ASB is service bus in the Cloud, not Service Bus in my app.

Comment: Agree with that.  With Service Bus you can most definitely do SOA (the 4 tenets definitely apply if you implement it right).  WCF is just an implementation.  And you configure your WCF bindings, based on the binding that best applies to your requirements.  One of these bindings could the the NetMessagingBinding that comes with the Service Bus.
But with it, you get some advantages like the decoupling, load leveling & balancing...

Comment: @Maxim: How does whether an endpoint speaks XML or JSON factor into a service being SOA or not? It doesn't. The way you are doing it is fundamentally broken on so many levels and the fact that it's talked about in books doesn't make it more right: just because Thomas Erl writes humongous books on intricacies of XML schemata, doesn't make him right.

Comment: @astaykov - there is no such thing as 'the cloud', there is only computation. ServiceBus comes from the DataBus pattern: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DataBusPattern - where instead of *objects* being looked up - you look up *services*. ASB doesn't qualify, it is a *message broker*. While in-proc queueing is not of big importance, routing of messages is, and since topic subscriptions in ASB don't target subscribers, but rather force you to create your own; again it is not a service bus. Please do tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: @Sam: the world has moved on from the four tenents - not that they have been invalidated; vocabulary and implementations change. That said, what you write about makes no sense - bindings in the WCF sense are really transport/channel communication/transport implementations -- how does that factor into anything? I can create a binding over a two file-locks with two nodes, flipping the lock on and off, if I want to. My service bus should still provide the abstractions inside my application for me, no matter the transport.

Comment: @MaximGershkovich - Some issues with WCF sample above: ( * You are using request-response, instead of a temporally decoupled channel ), ( * There seems to be confusion about what to do on failure ), ( * No inversion of lookup of where the service is ), ( * You are using a compiled proxy which is massively vulnerable to schamata changes ), ( * You are using SOAP, which, from a performance/optimisation perspective is seppuku ), ( * Breaking almost all of the fallacies of distributed computing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_Distributed_Computing )

Comment: @Henrik I'm sorry but I just don't buy most of what u've written above. Google - "temporally decoupled channel". I can't find a single result even defining this concept. There is no confusion about what to do in failure and if I wanted to I could easily wrap the above code in a "retry" structure - I've chosen not to do so because it isn't required in 99% of scenarios. No idea what u are talking about regarding inversion of lookup, again not a term I can find anywhere online. Yes it is a compiled proxy but it is coded against an interface which I again would argue works for 99% of scenarios.

Comment: Further, nowhere in the above code is it implied that I am using SOAP and infact the above example is taken from a NamedPipes based implementation. Honestly to me, allot of what you've written sounds like the typical crap I hear from programmers who like to use big words and make themselves seem smart as result. Personally I just like to build software that works and do so ontime, I'm not looking to build the ultimate generic solution or to prove my intelligence to anyone.

Comment: ... it would be hard for the receiver to know that it's not just a new message, should it have already gotten it. Not caring and talking about the 99% means that you don't care about the fallacies of distributed computing. If you only 99% availability, combining many such services lead to much lower percentage availability. About interfaces: it is not enough to say "compiled against an interface" - because you haven't specified what the interface is - why e.g. does the proxy care about the order that C# properties have been declared? Point being: the generator over-specifies the interface.